# Jupyter Notebook - No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found

Tags: python, linux, cmake, jupyter-notebook

I want to run my program inside Jupyter Notebook but I need to install face_recognition first using pip3 install face_recognition. But I keep on receiving this error

> > ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:    command: /home/opc/py36env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools,
> > tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> > '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/setup.py'"'"';f
> > = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import
> > setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> > '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> > bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-itbhhoxa
> > cwd: /tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/
> > Complete output (56 lines):   running bdist_wheel   running build
> > running build_py   package init file 'tools/python/dlib/**init**.py'
> > not found (or not a regular file)   running build_ext   Building
> > extension for Python 3.6.8 (default, Mar  9 2021, 15:08:44)   Invoking
> > CMake setup: 'cmake
> > /tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/tools/python
> > -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
> > -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/opc/py36env/bin/python3 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release'   -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5   -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done   -- Check
> > for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped   -- Detecting C compile
> > features   -- Detecting C compile features - done   CMake Error at
> > CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):
> > No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
>
> ```
> Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
> variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
> to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
> ```
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!   See also
> "/tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
> See also
> "/tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> File "/tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/setup.py",
> line 261, in 
> 'Topic :: Software Development',
> File "/home/opc/py36env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py",
> line 153, in setup
> return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
> dist.run_commands()
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
> self.run_command(cmd)
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
> cmd_obj.run()
> File "/home/opc/py36env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py",
> line 299, in run
> self.run_command('build')
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
> self.distribution.run_command(command)
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
> cmd_obj.run()
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
> self.run_command(cmd_name)
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
> self.distribution.run_command(command)
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
> cmd_obj.run()
> File "/tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/setup.py",
> line 134, in run
> self.build_extension(ext)
> File "/tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/setup.py",
> line 171, in build_extension
> subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
> raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)   subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake',
> '/tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/tools/python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6',
> '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/opc/py36env/bin/python3',
> '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
> ----------------------------------------   ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib   Running setup.py clean for dlib Failed to build dlib
> Installing collected packages: dlib
> Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: /home/opc/py36env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/setup.py'"'"';f
> = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import
> setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record /tmp/pip-record-y0hkle0_/install-record.txt
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/opc/py36env/include/site/python3.6/dlib
> cwd: /tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/
> Complete output (58 lines):
> running install
> running build
> running build_py
> package init file 'tools/python/dlib/**init**.py' not found (or not a regular file)
> running build_ext
> Building extension for Python 3.6.8 (default, Mar  9 2021, 15:08:44)
> Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake /tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/tools/python
> -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6
> -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/opc/py36env/bin/python3 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release'
> -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
> -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
> -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
> -- Detecting C compile features
> -- Detecting C compile features - done
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):
> No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
>
> ```
>   Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
>   variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
>   to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
>
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
> See also "/tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
> See also "/tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/setup.py",
> ```
>
> line 261, in 
> 'Topic :: Software Development',
> File "/home/opc/py36env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/**init**.py",
> line 153, in setup
> return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
> dist.run_commands()
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
> self.run_command(cmd)
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
> cmd_obj.run()
> File "/home/opc/py36env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py",
> line 61, in run
> return orig.install.run(self)
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/command/install.py", line 556, in run
> self.run_command('build')
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
> self.distribution.run_command(command)
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
> cmd_obj.run()
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
> self.run_command(cmd_name)
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
> self.distribution.run_command(command)
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
> cmd_obj.run()
> File "/tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/setup.py",
> line 134, in run
> self.build_extension(ext)
> File "/tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/setup.py",
> line 171, in build_extension
> subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
> raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
> subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '/tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/tools/python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=/tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.6',
> '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/opc/py36env/bin/python3',
> '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
> ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/opc/py36env/bin/python3 -u -c 'import
> io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-5zstrya1/dlib_5f4cec1247f74d1098b0e055d68c7ff3/setup.py'"'"';f
> = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**) if os.path.exists(**file**) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import
> setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record /tmp/pip-record-y0hkle0_/install-record.txt
> --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/opc/py36env/include/site/python3.6/dlib Check the logs for full
> command output.

same thing will happen if I try to install dlib using pip3 install dlib

Comment: So you need C++ compiler. As you have `gcc` as C compiler, you probably want to install `g++`.

Comment: is there a way to install g++ using pip?

Comment: Install g++ ( gcc-c++ ) with the same package install tool that you used for gcc.

Comment: can I use other compiler? because my current project using python instead of C++. Plus I never installed gcc before, is it pre-installed?

Comment: My program can run in my Windows and also in conda. But when I tried to run on Jupyter Notebook, the error occurs.